# Nietzsche on subconscious self-justification

Tags: nietzsche, quote

What is the quotation of Nietzsche where he says that he found himself somehow subconsciously lying to himself in order to feel better about something he did?

Comment: I think it's the whole thing...

Comment: @ScottRowe You mean the whole Nietzsche oeuvre?

Comment: Him, and everyone else, I think.

Comment: It's difficult to escape @ScottRowe wait!

Comment: do you think that it's best to seek justification from other people?